# Selection Sorting/bubble Sorting algorithm

Tags: java, arrays

I am newbie in terms of algorithm,and i don't know how to code it especially selection sorting or bubble sorting algorithm..

I am using Borland JBuilder3,can anyone help me??thanks

Comment: Wikipedia has articles on sorting algorithms.  That is the place to start.  Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask].  StackOverflow is not a "gimme teh codez" site (we won't write code for you from scratch), and you are expected to have done a bit of basic research before asking here.  Also when you ask you are expected to show the code you have written and explain what you don't understand.

Comment: In practice, you will most likely have no need to write a sort algorithm, because there are highly efficient methods in the JDK like [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) and [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically need to use those types of sorting the: `Arrays.sort()` function typically works great.

Otherwise these might help:

**Selection sort**

Explanation: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/selection_sort_algorithm.htm

Java Implementation:

```
final int[] arr = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }; // This is my array
    int min;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Assume first element is min
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                min = j;

            }
        }
        if (min != i) {
            final int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = temp;
        }
        System.out.println(arr[i]);// I print the in ascending order
    }
```

**Bubble Sort**

Explanation: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm

Java Implementation:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] numArray) {

    int n = numArray.length;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

            if (numArray[j - 1] > numArray[j]) {
                temp = numArray[j - 1];
                numArray[j - 1] = numArray[j];
                numArray[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```